# GSON not reading values correctly

Tags: json, api, gson

I'm trying to read this JSON:

[image]

And I can't seem to get it to work with GSON. I've used GSON successfully in the same project so I know how it works but I can't seem to get this JSON to work as intended. First in the class is rows, which is just an array of another class. The other class has three variables, a string named "code", a string named "name", and a array of another class called "statuses". However, I don't know how to put variables in this other class. It looks like an array but it's not. I cannot name a variable "0" in Java, so I looked that up (tried fixing it with Maps) but that did not work. How would you do this? It's weird because "statuses" always contains just that one entry, named '0', and the text is either "primary" or "secondary". Any help is appreciated.

I actually found this:

[image: new information]

Still not really sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Pojo design shoild be like this :-

```
public class ResultOutPut  {

private List<Rows> rows;

// getters and setters  

}

public class Rows {

private String code;

private String name;

private List<String> statuses;

// getters and setters  

}
```

Comment: As your statuses array contains list of string so In rows List<String> will be used. Use @SerializedName annotation on fields if your using ProGuard